# Using tryCatch for error handling with web Scraping

Tags: r

I have two links

```
> primary_link
[1] "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahaani_(2012_film)"
> secondary_link
[1] "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahaani"
```

For primary link I get an error

> read_html(primary_link)
>   Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404.

But for secondary link I am able to read perfectly.

With tryCatch I tried to write an error handler of the form where if primary link gives error try secondary link

The code I am trying is this

```
web_page <- tryCatch(read_html(primary_link),finally = read_html(secondary_link))
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You could also use the `http_error` function to figure out whether a page is accessible or not. This function returns `TRUE` in case of an error.

```
primary_link <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahaani_(2012_film)"
secondary_link <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahaani"

library(httr)
urls <- c(primary_link, secondary_link)

sapply(urls, http_error, config(followlocation = 0L), USE.NAMES = F)
###[1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go down this road, then I think the appropriate pattern would be to make a second `tryCatch` call in the event there be an error with the first link:

```
web_page <- tryCatch({
    read_html(primary_link)
}, error = function(e) {
    tryCatch({
        read_html(secondary_link)
    }, finally = { # cleanup for second call
    })
}, finally = {
    # cleanup for both calls
})
```

Answer (score 1):

`tryCatch()` can make for some twisted code and there's an alternative now from the `purrr` package. Also, since you're no doubt going to use this code more than once, you should wrap it in a function:

```
library(purrr)
library(httr)

primary_link <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahaani_(2012_film)"
secondary_link <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahaani"

GET_alt <- function(url_1, url_2, .verbose=TRUE) {

  # this wraps httr::GET in exception handling code in the
  # event the site is completely inaccessible and not just
  # issuing 40x errors

  sGET <- purrr::safely(GET)

  res <- sGET(url_1)

  # Now, check for whether it had a severe error or just 
  # didn't retrieve the content successfully and fetch
  # the alternate URL if so

  if (is.null(res$result) | (status_code(res$result) != 200)) {
    if (.verbose) message("Using alternate URL")
    res <- sGET(url_2)
  }

  # I'd do other error handling here besides just issue a 
  # warning, but I have no idea what you're doing so we'll
  # just issue a warning

  if (!is.null(res$result)) {
    warn_for_status(res$result)
  }

  return(res$result)

}

GET_alt(primary_link, secondary_link)
```